# Authorization in ASP.NET Core. Always 401 Unauthorized for [Authorize] attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, authorization, bearer-token

For the first time I'm creating Authorization in ASP.NET Core.
I used tutorial from here [TUTORIAL](https://dev.to/samueleresca/developing-token-authentication-using-aspnet-core)

The problem is when I sending request from postman:

```
Authorization:Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6I...
```

to my method in controller decorated with [Authorize] attribute.

I receive `401 Unauthorized` always...  I saw comments bellow that tutorial and it seems that some people have similar issue also. I've no idea how I can solve this problem.

Comment: `JwtBearerMiddleware` should produce a lot of log events. Add a logger in `Startup.Configure` method and check it.

Comment: I found solution, problem was with middleware order :)

Comment: @DiPix, It will be helpful if you post your answer here so that we can see what happened. Otherwise it is not helpful for others who lands on this page.

Comment: Every upvote on @Ray's comment should represent the people looking for what DiPix did. :|

Comment: @Irwin I posted the answer :)

Comment: Please rename or remove this question, because answer you gave has nothing to do with debugging.

Comment: I think you can check this answer 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/63446357/4307338

Comment: In my case it was an issue with the JWT. Check the response headers for: `WWW-Authenticate: Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The signature is invalid"`

Answer (score 37, accepted):

At the request of others here is the answer:

The problem was with the middleware order in Startup.cs

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    ConfigureAuth(app); // your authorisation configuration

    app.UseMvc();
}
```

Why middleware order is important? If we put `app.UseMvc()` first - then the MVC actions would get in the routing and if they see the Authorize attribute they will take control of its handling and that's why we receives 401 Unauthorized error.

I hope it helps someone ;)

Comment: If you're using ASP.NET Core 3.0 previews, swap `UseMvc` with `UseRouting`.

Comment: In my case I forgot to add `app.UseAuthentication()` before `app.UseMvc()`, which is probably what the `ConfigureAuth(app)` above calls

Comment: almost 2 years and I still got this!!

Comment: @BaltzarMattson can you make a new answer

Comment: @goamn Unsure what a new answer will provide, just make sure the order is:
`app.UseAuthentication()` then `app.UseMvc()`

Comment: @BaltzarMattson This answer is not obvious and someone has to read all the answers, then all the comments, and only then will they be able to understand. Up to you :)

Answer (score 27):

in ASP.NET Core 3.0, i had the same problem, what worked for me was:

```
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

in StartUp.Configure method.

This doc shows typical ordering of middleware components:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-3.0

Comment: After a few hours of research, this was the issue that I had... (on .net 6) my gosh. Thanks @eugenecp

Answer (score 7):

If you are using ASP.NET Core 3.0

Check this order

`app.UseAuthentication();`

`app.UseRouting();` //must be below `app.UseAuthentication();`

If you are using ASP.NET Core < 3.0

Just replace the `app.UseRouting();` by `app.UseMvc();`

i.e:

`app.UseAuthentication();`

`app.UseMvc();` //must be below `app.UseAuthentication();`

Comment: I think you got the order for 3.0 wrong. The correct order can be seen at - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-3.0

Answer (score 3):

In my case I was following [coreApi](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/01/08/aspnet-core-22-role-based-authorization-tutorial-with-example-api#users-controller-cs),[angularClient](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/11/22/angular-7-role-based-authorization-tutorial-with-example) tutorial, but getting unauthorized error every time also In my case angular application is running under Core Api project.

So then I changed the order like this and it works now

```
   public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env,ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseSpaStaticFiles();


        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });


        app.UseSpa(spa =>
        {
            // To learn more about options for serving an Angular SPA from ASP.NET Core,
            // see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501

            spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
            }
        });


         loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();

        // global cors policy
        app.UseCors(x => x
            .AllowAnyOrigin()
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowCredentials());

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

My ConfigureServices and Configure methods (Asp.Net Core 3.1.0) in the Startup class:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("AllowsAll", builder =>
        {
            builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader();
        });
    });

    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        ...
    });

    services.AddControllers();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseCors(options => options.AllowAnyOrigin());

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });
}
```

My controller:

```
[Authorize]
[EnableCors("AllowsAll")]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class MyController : MyController
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank You! Thank You! Thank You! I previously had UseRouting() before UseAuthentication() and UseAuthorization(). This worked great while running it locally, but returned a 401 for everything once deployed to a web server. I saw answers saying I should have UseAuthentication() before UseRouting(), so I was trying to put UseAuthentication() and UseAuthorization() both before UseRouting() which did not work. Putting those three in the order you described above ended a day's worth of headache for me.

Comment: Mark as answer please.

Answer (score 3):

for .NET CORE 3.0 or higher user this order in "configure" located in StartUp.cs

```
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();
```

Comment: This Answer already existed exactly above.

Answer (score 2):

I fixes mine by changing the UseAuthentication() and order of UseAuthentication() and UseRouting()  in the Configure method on Startup class.

Before

```
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseAuthentication();
```

After

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case  i also was using app.MapWhen(code), and app.UseAuthentication(); should be  before mapWhen like this

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.MapWhen();
app.UseMvc();
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Along with order of middlewares, parameters of token must be matched with Authentication parameters (specifically, secret key).

I made a mistake that I had used different secret keys in both places which was returning status code 401.

Sharing screenshots of code (.net core 3.1) that may assist any one.

> Startup.cs > ConfigureServices()
> [image: startup.cs file]

> Login Controller logic
> [image: Token generation logic]

Answer (score -4):

Solution for me was check the correctly order of middle-wares and other stuff in Configure method of Startup. Generally `app.UseMvc();`