# Cannot verify AAD token obtained via adal-angular4

Tags: c#, angular, azure-active-directory

I've got a web app written in Angular 6 using the [adal-angular4 package](https://github.com/benbaran/adal-angular4) to perform authentication via AAD. I am trying to get the UI to communicate with a backend service using this token. However, I keep getting a 401 Unauthorized response when trying to call the server's APIs even when all of the validation should be turned off. Inspecting the token with [jwt.io](https://jwt.io) yields an "invalid signature" error at the bottom of the page, but otherwise the token is readable.

As for AAD configuration, both the frontend app and backend service are registered as separate AAD apps, so any references to `clientId` or `clientAppId` refer to the client's application id while `apiServiceId` refers to that of the backend service. I have also exposed a scope in the backend app registration, added an API permission to the frontend app registration for that scope, and authorized the frontend app in the backend app. I have also enabled implicit grant for both id tokens and access tokens for both services. Here's the relevant code:

app.module.ts:

```
// imports

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ ... ],
  imports: [ ... ],
  providers: [
    AdalService,
    AdalGuard,
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: AdalInterceptor, multi: true }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { AdalService } from 'adal-angular4';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Tour of Heroes';

  constructor(private adalService: AdalService) {
    adalService.init(environment.adalConfig);
  }
}
```

toolbar.component.ts (where the login button lives):

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AdalService } from 'adal-angular4';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-toolbar',
  templateUrl: './toolbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./toolbar.component.css']
})
export class ToolbarComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private adalService: AdalService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.adalService.handleWindowCallback();

    console.log(this.adalService.userInfo);
  }

  login() {
    this.adalService.login();
  }

  logout() {
    this.adalService.logOut();
  }

  get authenticated(): boolean {
    return this.adalService.userInfo.authenticated;
  }

  get username(): string {
    return this.adalService.userInfo.userName;
  }
}
```

environment.ts:

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  adalConfig: {
    tenant: 'MyTenant.onmicrosoft.com',
    clientId: '<clientId>',
    endpoints: {
      "https://localhost:8443/api": "<apiServiceId>"
    }
  }
};
```

From Startup.cs:

```
// TODO: Put strings in config
const string tenantId = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx";
const string clientAppId = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx";
appBuilder.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(
    new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
    {
        Tenant = "MyTenant.onmicrosoft.com",
        TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            // Authentication still fails when all bools below are set to false.
            NameClaimType = ClaimTypes.Name,
            AuthenticationType = "AADJwt",
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            RequireExpirationTime = true,
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidAudiences = new[]
            {
                clientAppId,
            },
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidIssuers = new[]
            {
                $"https://sts.windows.net/{tenantId}/",
                $"https://login.microsoftonline.net/{tenantId}/",
            },
        }
    });
```

Controller.cs:

```
[Authorize]
public class MyController : ApiController
{
    // APIs
}
```

Here's what the token looks like according to jwt.io:

Header:

```
{
  "typ": "JWT",
  "alg": "RS256",
  "x5t": "nbCwW11w3XkB-xUaXwKRSLjMHGQ",
  "kid": "nbCwW11w3XkB-xUaXwKRSLjMHGQ"
}
```

Payload:

```
{
  "aud": "<clientId>",
  "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/<tenantId>/",
  "iat": 1547682045,
  "nbf": 1547682045,
  "exp": 1547685945,
  "aio": "AVQAq/8KAAAAONOm6T/DrjjHFUTe/uPcsFcv2Iye85/EtY+cFYyq+X69OcQlHyqqPcYF0cjRWHyIRnnkcr7PkSTHp5bRb40AGUhVS5yuG53RCO0lNAQCBfE=",
  "amr": [
    "pwd",
    "rsa"
  ],
  "email": "asdf@asdf.com",
  "family_name": "asdf",
  "given_name": "asdf",
  "idp": "https://sts.windows.net/72f988bf-86f1-41af-91ab-2d7cd011db47/",
  "ipaddr": "x.x.x.x",
  "name": "asdf asdf",
  "nonce": "1a80bf29-e720-4abc-91c3-bc37c066286a",
  "oid": "f4f2107f-a760-4db4-b5d6-9a9fb6d2cb6b",
  "sub": "ll04ffs2YHBR0esHBJp9vevJEbgITRC9ushAQdZbB7U",
  "tid": "d93850bc-6bc9-4a51-9975-13e297ee0710",
  "unique_name": "asdf@asdf.com",
  "uti": "A7mEPuQ6REKQIFShTCoDAA",
  "ver": "1.0"
}
```

Why would my authentication be failing? Everything in the token that I want to verify seems to match what I'm expecting, so I have no idea why I keep getting a 401. The fact that jwt.io can't validate the signature makes me think something is wrong there; what could it be?

**Edit**: Added AAD setup info and provided an updated environment.ts, which includes the `endpoints` array. From what I'm reading, the `AdalInterceptor` will automatically acquire and inject access tokens based on `endpoints`. The token that I get is functionally identical to the one shown above. Is there some other configuration I'm missing?

Comment: That looks like an Id token that you are sending. Your front-end should typically acquire an access token for your API using the API's client id or App Id URI.

Comment: What's the difference? Do you know how to obtain an access token using adal-angular4? I'm very new to web development so a lot of this is foreign to me

Comment: I'm not familiar with ADAL for Angular :/ But IIRC you specify the endpoints object such that it knows to acquire and attach the right token for HTTP requests to a particular domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out I was setting up the middleware in the incorrect order in startup. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46788190/2494394), where the asker had to register AAD authentication earlier in the pipeline in order to get things working. Otherwise you may just get 401 responses every time regardless of configuration.