# Visual studio's ASP.NET core with angular template always returns 401

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.10.2. I created an ASP.net core 5 project from their template "ASP.net core with Angular" with Authentication checked. But Every time I request an API Method marked with the attribute `[Authorize]` I get 401.

Their template was supposed to work with no problem but I got some trouble logging in. I fixed them but, the only problem I can't figure out how to fix is the 401 code returned ASP.

I read the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-api-authorization?view=aspnetcore-5.0) several times but I could not find any useful information.

The thing is: I can create accounts and login with no problem. When I login, the server returns the token. From the Angular app it shows the name of the logged-in user. But when to access an [Authorize] controller it returns 404.

Here is [the link of the project](https://github.com/Guervyl/Angular-identity-test-error) I pushed to github for better debugging.

Here is the startup code:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

            services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

            services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

            services.AddIdentityServer()
                .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>(op =>
                {
                    // I added these lines because I was getting the error "Error: Client Angular_identity_test is not allowed access to scope Angular."
                    op.Clients[0].AllowedScopes = new List<string> { "Angular", "identity", "testAPI" };

                    op.ApiScopes = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer.ApiScopeCollection(new List<ApiScope> { new ApiScope("Angular"), new ApiScope("identity"), new ApiScope("testAPI") });
                    op.ApiResources.AddApiResource("Angular", conf => conf.WithScopes(new string[] { "Angular", "identity", "testAPI" }));
                    op.ApiResources.AddApiResource("identity", conf => conf.WithScopes(new string[] { "Angular", "identity", "testAPI" }));
                    op.ApiResources.AddApiResource("testAPI", conf => conf.WithScopes(new string[] { "Angular", "identity", "testAPI" }));
                });

            services.AddAuthentication()
                .AddIdentityServerJwt();
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddRazorPages();
            // In production, the Angular files will be served from this directory
            services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
            {
                configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
            });
        }

// In public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            if (!env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
            }

            app.UseRouting();

            // I added this line because some people say that fixed their problems.
            app.UseCors(x => x
            .AllowAnyOrigin()
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader());

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseIdentityServer();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });

            app.UseSpa(spa =>
            {
                // To learn more about options for serving an Angular SPA from ASP.NET Core,
                // see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501

                spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
                }
            });
```

In the appsettings.json there is:

```
"IdentityServer": {
    "Clients": {
      "Angular_identity_test": {
        "Profile": "IdentityServerSPA"
      }
    }
  }
```

And the controller that keeps return 401:

```
[Authorize()]
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
    {
        private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
        {
            "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
        };

        private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;

        public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
        {
            var rng = new Random();
            return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
            {
                Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
                TemperatureC = rng.Next(-20, 55),
                Summary = Summaries[rng.Next(Summaries.Length)]
            })
            .ToArray();
        }
```

Comment: I built your project on my own machine and got this message with the 401 `Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The audience 'Angular, identity, testAPI' is invalid"`. It looks like the problem lies in those scope lines you added. If I had more time I'd examine this more closely but I hope it helps you a little bit.

Comment: The problem is, if I remove the scopes I added, I get the error: "Error: Client Angular_identity_test is not allowed access to scope Angular."

Answer (score 1):

This will be a proxy issue.  In your CLIENTAPP go to the proxy.conf.js and add your controllers route into the PROXY_CONFIG->context array (like "/weatherforecast" is). Then restart your application. You don't need to change .NET Core middleware or services.

**UPDATE**

I added this DI BASE_URL into my service constructor and it works fine now.

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient, @Inject('BASE_URL') private bUrl: string) {
    this.baseUrl = bUrl + "api/v1/items"; // my endpoint
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So you say,  `But when to access a [Authorize] controller it returns 404.` use this below code, instead of `[Authorize]`.

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Bearer")]
```

It will resolve your issue.

**UPDATE**

Use this below code and i assume that your `Token` is place of `appsettings.development.json` file. like `"TokenKey":"super secret key",`

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                 .AddJwtBearer(options => {
                     
                     options.TokenValidationParameters=new TokenValidationParameters
                     {
                         
                          ValidateIssuerSigningKey=true,
                          IssuerSigningKey=new SymmetricSecurityKey( Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(config["TokenKey"]) ),
                          ValidateIssuer=false,
                          ValidateAudience=false
                     };

                 });
```

Hope it will resolve your issue.

Comment: It doesn't work if I add the attribute `AuthenticationSchemes` to Bearer. I got the error: System.InvalidOperationException: No authentication handler is registered for the scheme 'Bearer'. The registered schemes are: Identity.Application, Identity.External, Identity.TwoFactorRememberMe, Identity.TwoFactorUserId, idsrv, idsrv.external, IdentityServerJwt, IdentityServerJwtBearer. Did you forget to call AddAuthentication().Add[SomeAuthHandler]("Bearer",...)?

Comment: @user3502626 I updated my answer.please check.

Comment: I'm still getting 401 with your update. To make sure I did everything as you mentioned. Here is the appsettings.development.json content: `{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "IdentityServer": {
    "Key": {
      "Type": "Development"
    }
  },
  "TokenKey": "Test super secret key"
}`

Comment: And the Authentication configuration: `services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                 .AddJwtBearer(options =>
                 {

                     options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                     {

                         ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true, IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["TokenKey"])), ValidateIssuer = false, ValidateAudience = false
                     };

                 })
                .AddIdentityServerJwt();`

Comment: Please note the `.AddIdentityServerJwt();` added by the template creators.

Comment: @user3502626 may be your problem is middleware order. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43574552/authorization-in-asp-net-core-always-401-unauthorized-for-authorize-attribute

Comment: It is not. This template has been created by the Microsoft developers. I did not create the code neither modify the other of order of the configuration. Take a look at the configuration in my question. The order is correct.

Comment: @user3502626 did you make a process make tokens in your application? I didn't even seen it i  your github repository.

Comment: I don't understand the **process make tokens**. What do you mean by that? I guess the `AddApiAuthorization()` or `AddIdentityServerJwt()` was supposed to handle the bearer token authentication. What is missing in the configuration? I didn't add, remove nor change anything to the configuration other than the scopes.

Comment: You can also download the project from GitHub and test it to see what is going on.